# List Index Out Of Range : PYTHON

Tags: python, list

Even though I am getting valid Prints but still I am getting List Index out of range. The list where I am getting "Out of Range" error is "lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE"

```
if((int(len(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1]))) > 1):
    print("Length={0} and Value={1}".format(len(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1]), lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1]))
    for l_inner_element in (lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log:][1]):
        if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index_can_log][1]):
            #Some Calculation 
        else:
            break
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Length=3 and Value=340
Traceback (most recent call last):
    for l_inner_element in (lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log:][1]): 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**EDITED FROM HERE (CODE MODIFIED TO INCORPORATE SUGGESTION):**
The List "lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE" is a List of Lists. Now let us say I want the comparison to start fresh from index "index_shadow_log" (SubList "index_shadow_log" onwards)

for l_inner_element in (lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log:]):

Thanks for your answers, I now understood that the meaning of this for loop would be start iteration for List "lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE" starting from index "index_shadow_log:"

This is my extracted code:

```
for index in range(len(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE)):
    for l_index in range(len(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE)):
        #print(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[l_index][0])
        #print(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[l_index][1])
        if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[l_index][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][1]):  #Consider for comparison only CAN IDs
            print("matching")
            #print(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index][0])
            #print(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[l_index][0])
            index_can_log = index                                           #Position where CAN Log is to be compared
            index_shadow_log = l_index                                      #Position from where CAN Shadow Log is to be considered
            print("Length={0} and Value={1}".format(len(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1]), lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1]))
            bMatchFound = 1
            for l_inner_element in (lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log:]):    #Start comparison
                if(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1] == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index_can_log][1]): #Compare individual element
                    dump_file.write("\n")
                    dump_file.write("SHADOW: " + str(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log]))                #Dump if equal
                    writer_two.writerow(lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][0])                               #Update CSV File                
                    dump_file.write("\n")
                    dump_file.write("CAN: " + str(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index_can_log]))                     #Dump if equal
                    writer_one.writerow(lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index_can_log][0])                             #Update CSV File                
                    if(index_can_log < (input_file_one_row_count - 1)):                                 #Update CAN LOG Index
                        index_can_log = index_can_log  + 1
                    if(index_can_log >= (input_file_one_row_count - 1)):
                        break
                else:
                    bMatchFound = 0
                    break
            if(bMatchFound == 0):
                break   
dump_file.close()
```

I need to get rid of parenthesis (Sorry coming from C/C++ background we love braces and parenthesis :-P) and make the code a lot cleaner. Thanks all for your suggestions

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but: `if((int(len`... Most unusual. Isn't the result of `len` already an int?

Comment: `lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log]` is *not the same thing* as `lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log:]`

Comment: Holy unnecessary parentheses, Batman!

Comment: How do I make the inner loop start at index "index_shadow_log" (Its a list of lists). lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log] is giving me a valid output but line "l_inner_element in (lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log:][1])" fails. 

Sorry for the dirty code. I am amateur in PYTHON and I am from C/C++ background but I have to do this script in PYTHON only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare:

```
lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1]
```

with

```
lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log:][1]
```

The first indexes `lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE`, then indexes whatever that returned. The second **slices** `lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE`; this returns a new list. You then indexed that sliced list. If that sliced list has only 1 element, then indexing the second is going to fail.

You really need to cut back on the parentheses here, and simplify the code somewhat. Use a temporary variable to store the indexed element:

```
value = lstSHADOW_LOG_TABLE[index_shadow_log][1]
if value:
    print("Length={0} and Value={1}".format(len(value), value))
    for l_inner_element in value:
        if value == lstCAN_LOG_TABLE[index_can_log][1]:
            #Some Calculation 
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I could differentiate between slicing and indexing  and have modified the code :). It works fine now.

P.S: My code is still ugly though :-P